# What it the meaning of <F_01> added by 3d view to the object name?

Tags: interface

Does anybody know what's the meaning of that suffix I've found while browsing a .blend file sent by a friend?

[image]

Comment: This is a marker in the timeline (open a timeline view, you should see it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you add a marker on the timeline, all the objects will include the suffix F (frame) and the number of the frame you added the marker to.
If you move to another frame, you can see that the suffix disappear.

[image: A Cube]

[image: Adding a Marker]

[image: Cube F_01]

[image: if you move to another frame, you can see that the suffix disapear]